# Adding the column name in excel file by python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have to columns value as [image input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJqh7.png) in .csv. I need the output as [Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJjF6.png) with col1 and col2 add on the column. Please let me know, how can we get it?

Comment: Is it the answer you're looking for? [Solution-link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/45315/94155)

Comment: Please avoid posting images to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pandas, reading with no header creates columns that by default are numerical, i.e. 0, 1, 2...
You can rename these to Col1, Col2 etc or whatever you want.
    import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.read_csv("csv_filename.csv", header=None)
df = df.rename(columns={0:"Col1",1:"Col2"})
df.to_csv("csv_filename_out.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for your revert